# Number of bits N for M states

Tags: combinatorics

How many bits N are required to represent a controller with M different states?

So am I supposed to find N such that $2^N = M$ ? Also what if the integer $2^N > M$?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need $N\ge\frac{ln(M)}{ln(2)}$.  It is okay if $2^N>M$, you'll just have some extra bit combinations you won't need.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!